# How to sort the top n value and saving them in a metrix with others turning zero in Tensorflow?

Tags: sorting, tensorflow

In Tensorflow,for example :`[6,3,1,5,8,2,4]`

if I use the `tf.gather` and the `tf.nn.top_k` to get the top 3 in the metrix

the result will be `[6,5,8]`

However what I want is `[6,0,0,5,8,0,0]`

plz help me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I get a solution,
first use the tf.nn.top_k to get the top 3's index and the values.
second use the tf.sparse_to_dense,and use the index and the values to fill.